# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

According to Google, this error seems to happen quite often, and now it happens to me. I read lots of the posts I found, but unfortunately my error remains...

I took a `countries.json` (I think from the OpenLayers repo or a similar one), put it in a local `data` folder and build something to display it (in a Vue environment). That works fine.

Then I extracted Afghanistan (the very first country in the list) and put its geojson data in its own file, `/data/afg.geojson'. I also tested it on` https://geojson.io` first - it does work. But in my app it does not, instead this error is thrown:

```
VM49900:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getObject (JSONFeature.js?f68c:191)
    at GeoJSON.JSONFeature.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js?f68c:61)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (featureloader.js?6c5f:86)
```

This is, what Afghanistan looks like:

```json
{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],[62.230651,35.270664],[62.984662,35.404041],[63.193538,35.857166],[63.982896,36.007957],[64.546479,36.312073],[64.746105,37.111818],[65.588948,37.305217],[65.745631,37.661164],[66.217385,37.39379],[66.518607,37.362784],[67.075782,37.356144],[67.83,37.144994],[68.135562,37.023115],[68.859446,37.344336],[69.196273,37.151144],[69.518785,37.608997],[70.116578,37.588223],[70.270574,37.735165],[70.376304,38.138396],[70.806821,38.486282],[71.348131,38.258905],[71.239404,37.953265],[71.541918,37.905774],[71.448693,37.065645],[71.844638,36.738171],[72.193041,36.948288],[72.63689,37.047558],[73.260056,37.495257],[73.948696,37.421566],[74.980002,37.41999],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.575893,37.020841],[74.067552,36.836176],[72.920025,36.720007],[71.846292,36.509942],[71.262348,36.074388],[71.498768,35.650563],[71.613076,35.153203],[71.115019,34.733126],[71.156773,34.348911],[70.881803,33.988856],[69.930543,34.02012],[70.323594,33.358533],[69.687147,33.105499],[69.262522,32.501944],[69.317764,31.901412],[68.926677,31.620189],[68.556932,31.71331],[67.792689,31.58293],[67.683394,31.303154],[66.938891,31.304911],[66.381458,30.738899],[66.346473,29.887943],[65.046862,29.472181],[64.350419,29.560031],[64.148002,29.340819],[63.550261,29.468331],[62.549857,29.318572],[60.874248,29.829239],[61.781222,30.73585],[61.699314,31.379506],[60.941945,31.548075],[60.863655,32.18292],[60.536078,32.981269],[60.9637,33.528832],[60.52843,33.676446],[60.803193,34.404102],[61.210817,35.650072]]]}}
```

And this is the part of my code that should display the geojson (as mentioned: it works with countries.geojson):

```js
// Vue.js
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.prepareGeoJson()
  },
  methods: {
    prepareGeoJson (url) {
      this.gsSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: '/data/afg.geojson'
      })
      this.gsLayer.setSource(this.gsSource)
      this.gsLayer.setStyle(new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'green', width: 3 })
      }))
    },
    // Test Json
    toggleTestGeoJson (geojson) {
      this.olMap.addLayer(this.gsLayer)
    },
  }
}
```

The original `countries.json` that I use, is here:
https://dl.rowild.at/countries.geojson

Other things I can say:

- the file is minified
- the network response in "200" OK
- I work with VSCode...

Any idea, where my error is?

Comment: GeoJSON data should start with `FeatureCollection` wrapper: `{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature" ...`

Comment: Not when I only use one feature... geojson.io still displays the file correctly!

Comment: Problem might also be file extension `.geojson` not being listed in MIME types on your server.

Comment: No, I have troubles with my app, indeed :) – I just tried to add "FeatureCollection" to my Afghanistan file. It still does not work. (It still does work on geojson.io) – As mentioned below, the content-type returned is html, not geojson... I have no idea why. Do you?

Comment: But "countries.geojson" works.

Comment: On a side note: if I do NOT use FeatureCollection, geojson.io wraps it anyway. Thanks, @TomazicM !

Comment: I just copied "countires.geojson" and named it "countires-copy.geojson". Not this copied file is also not recgonized. Even though it is content-wise completely the same... This is quite strange...

Comment: Try to use postman https://www.postman.com/ instead of your JavaScript to send request with  your afg.geojson. You will see full html response, that hopefully will describe the error

Answer (score 3):

The text/body of the response would be useful to know. I have encountered this parsing error many times and it's always because the response is HTML, not JSON. The "<" character is the start of every HTML file. A 200 response does not necessarily mean that the response is returning what you requested.

Comment: There is indeed a difference: when I load "countires.geojson", the ResponseHeader's Content-Type is "application/geo+json, charset=UTF-8", but loading "Afghanistan" it is "text/html; charset=UTF-8". I really do not understand! Both files are geojson, the loading function is the same... all I do is replacing "data/countries.geojson" with "/data/afg.geojson".

Comment: The response type is indeed the problem. However, I have no clue as to why it changes form one geojson file to another. (I am working in a webpack 4 environment, setup by vue-cli...)

Answer (score 0):

```
import countriesData from "./countries.geojson";
methods: {
    prepareGeoJson (url) {
      this.gsSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url:countriesData 
      })
      this.gsLayer.setSource(this.gsSource)
      this.gsLayer.setStyle(new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'green', width: 3 })
      }))
    },
    // Test Json
    toggleTestGeoJson (geojson) {
      this.olMap.addLayer(this.gsLayer)
    },
  }
```

Comment: Please add a reason why you add this code. Only the code itself does not explain enough, especially since it does not pick up on the fact, that only ONE country is tested in the question.